# Find a basis $\gamma$ for $\mathbb{F^3}$ s.t $[v]_\gamma = u$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $u=\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3 \end{pmatrix}, v=\begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{F^3}$ non-zero vectors.
> Find a basis $\gamma = \{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ for $\mathbb{F^3}$ s.t $\sum_{i=1}^3 u_iw_i = v$.

I have no clue where to start from although I understand what I am looking for. I guess the fact those vectors are non-zeros is given so I can find a basis which includes them, but I don’t know how this can help.

I hope to get a little push rather than the full answer, thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify your notation?

Comment: @serpens Rephrased, hope it is clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $u_1\neq0,u_2\neq0,u_3\neq0$.

Let $e_1,e_2,e_3$ be the standard basis for $\Bbb F^3$. Since
$$e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \ ; \ e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \ ; \ e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},$$
we have
$$v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2+v_3e_3.$$
$\mathbf{\text{Case} \  1:}$ All components of $v$ are nonzero. I will leave it up to you to solve it.

$\mathbf{\text{Case} \  2:}$ One of the components of $v$ is zero.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $v_1=0$. Thus,
$$\tag{*}\label{*}v=v_2e_2+v_3e_3.$$
We want to find a basis $\gamma=\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ such that
$$\tag{**}\label{**}v=u_1w_1+u_2w_2+u_3w_3.$$
Note that we can go from $(\ref{*})$ to $(\ref{**})$ by means of the following educated guess:
$$\tag{***}\label{***}e_1=w_1 \ ; \ e_2=\frac{1}{v_2}\left(u_1w_1+u_2w_2\right) \ ; \ e_3=\frac{u_3}{v_3}w_3.$$
Solving $(\ref{***})$ to $w_1,w_2,w_3$, we find
$$\boxed{w_1:=e_1 \ ; \ w_2:=\frac{1}{u_2}\left(v_2e_2-u_1e_1\right) \ ; \ w_3:=\frac{v_3}{u_3}e_3.}$$

$\mathbf{\text{Case} \  3:}$ Two of the components of $v$ are zero. I will leave it up to you to solve it.